# Query to Transpose with values matching column header

Tags: ms-access, group-by, vba, transform

[image]

This one is a bit tricky.  As some of the values in table1 will matches with the 
column header in table2 and record being group by ID, I tried with below query but failed:

```
TRANSFORM Persons
SELECT ID, City, Country
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ID, City, Country
PIVOT Group;
```

Comment: @HansUP it's MS Access, i keep putting MySql as a habbit...i'll take it out

Comment: If you add your data as copy&paste-able text, it would be easier to try things. http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html  (we can use "Parse table" to get the original data).

Comment: Are ID+City+Country always linked as in the example? i.e. is ID the City ID?

Comment: @Andre  if you're saying if A is always IL then no.  Will it be easier if otherwise?  Thanks

Comment: It doesn't really matter - but if City "defines" a row (together with ID), it should be the second column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're almost there - you are missing the aggregate function for the TRANSFORM clause (that is SUM in your case), and with `Group` being a reserved word, it should be in [square brackets].

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Persons)
SELECT ID, City, Country
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ID, City, Country
PIVOT [Group];
```

Answer (score 2):

That's just a simple pivot. I don't see anything that gets in the way.

A similar question was "[Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15931607/3227403)".

But I'd rather read up about pivoting with VB and Access.
On MSDN you can find the [TRANSFORM Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192901.aspx).

Comment: it seems like the link are for MySql..I've taken away the tab, it's meant for Access, thanks

Comment: The second link (TRANSFORM) is for Access.

Comment: I appreciate it but it's kinda urgent so I can't really 'study' it, I've edited my post on what I attempted, it's still not working

Comment: I don't think Pivot is able to achieve what I'm trying to do here.  It requires multiple data being tranform instead of 1.  Thanks for your hints thou

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this SQL.

```
TRANSFORM Count(Grouping.Country) AS CountOfCountry
SELECT ID, City, Country
FROM Grouping
GROUP BY ID,City,Country
PIVOT Group;
```

That gives me this.
[image]

I think all you can do is count, so the final result will be a little different that what you are showing in your example.  I could be wrong, but I think that's as close as you can get.

Comment: I do need the number display under G1/G2/etc to be correct, but thanks for your attempts!